# strtotime() throws false on a formatted date

Tags: php, date, timestamp, strtotime

I'm having a problem with converting a formatted date string into a integer timestamp. I'm using a datepicker to input a field such as `DD/MM/YY` and I'm using `strtotime` to change it.

**Example usage**

```
$date_from = (!empty($_POST['datefrom'])) ? (string) $db->sql_escape($_POST['datefrom']) : false;
$date_to   = (!empty($_POST['dateto'])) ? (string) $db->sql_escape($_POST['dateto']) : false;

$time_from = (!empty($_POST['timefrom'])) ? (string) $db->sql_escape($_POST['timefrom']) : '';
$time_to   = (!empty($_POST['timeto'])) ? (string) $db->sql_escape($_POST['timeto']) : '';
```

**Dumps**

```
var_dump($_POST); 
var_dump($date_from . ' ' . $time_from);
var_dump($date_to . ' ' . $time_to);
```

*Outputs*

```
array(4) {
  ["datefrom"]=>
  string(10) "23/03/2011"
  ["dateto"]=>
  string(10) "18/04/2011"
  ["timefrom"]=>
  string(5) "01:26"
  ["timeto"]=>
  string(5) "04:44"
}
string(16) "23/03/2011 01:26"
string(16) "18/04/2011 04:44"
```

Now you can see each variable are not empty, now nothing is returning (except `false`) when using `strtotime` with this:

```
$range_from = strtotime($date_from . ' ' . $time_from);
$range_to   = strtotime($date_to . ' ' . $time_to);

var_dump($range_from);
var_dump($range_to);
```

*Outputs*

```
bool(false)
bool(false)
```

Now that's where I'm stuck thinking why it's not converting a `DD/MM/YY HH:MM` into a timestamp, I hardly can find what's wrong with it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See http://php.net/strtotime

> Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats
>   are disambiguated by looking at the
>   separator between the various
>   components: if the separator is a
>   slash (/), then the American m/d/y is
>   assumed; whereas if the separator is a
>   dash (-) or a dot (.), then the
>   European d-m-y format is assumed.

23/03/2011 in m/d/y is invalid, as such the function returns false.

Comment: That's a bit of a wtf, why not default to system standard?

Comment: Defaulting to system standard would be even more problematic, since that means that code that works on one system breaks on the next