# PHP Date function

Tags: php, date

I meet a trouble with php data function.

echo strtotime("31/05/2011");

It prints empty.

What's problem with this?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [strtotime() throws false on a formatted date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5736205/strtotime-throws-false-on-a-formatted-date)

Comment: the problem is you didnt read the [third note in the PHP Manual for `strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php#refsect1-function.strtotime-notes) explaining what the problem is

Comment: @Gordon. Thanks for answer. Thanks a lot. I have changed date format to "-".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**DD**/MM/YYYY Is not a valid [date format](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php) (The manual outlines it must follow one of the [supported date and time formats](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php).) So, instead, it should be **MM**/DD/YYYY:

```
echo strtotime("05/31/2011");
```

Or, I guess as others have posted, the european (ISO8601 Notations) version uses hyphens:

```
echo strtotime("31-05-2011");
```

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Use dashes instead of forward slashes.

```
echo strtotime("31-05-2011"); // outputs 1306821600
```

Answer (score 1):

For European formatted dates (DD-MM-YYYY) use dashes not slashes:

```
echo strtotime('31-05-2011');
```

Answer (score 1):

`echo strtotime("2011-05-31");`

Answer (score 1):

How about using php's [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) functions?

```
DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '31/05/2011');
```